# How to import "compile-regexp" in a lisp program?

Tags: regex, emacs, lisp, common-lisp

I am new to LISP and want to run a program containing a function as shown below:

```
(defun number-string-p (s)
  (match-regexp
   #.(compile-regexp "^\\([+-]\\|\\)\\([0-9][0-9.,]*\\|[0-9.,]*[0-9]\\)$") s))
```

I get `COMPILE-REGEXP is undefined` while running it. It seems `match-regexp` and `compile-regexp` are not built-in functions in LISP. What should I do in this regard? Is there any package to import?
I searched a lot but could not resolve the problem.

Comment: Hello, the "de-facto" regexp lib for Common Lisp is cl-ppcre: https://edicl.github.io/cl-ppcre/ It does NOT contain these two functions, so I have little clues either. Maybe are you running a function part of a bigger program and you didn't load all its dependencies? You should tell us more about this program. Can you show a .asd file? Or the `defpackage` at the top of the file where `numbre-string-p` is?

Answer (score 3):

`compile-regexp` is a function that Allegro CL provided long ago, and still in fact does provide, but only as backwards compatibility: see [here](https://franz.com/support/documentation/10.1/doc/operators/excl/compile-regexp.htm).

If you want to make this code run in a Lisp other than Allegro then you will either need to write a compatible shim around something like [CL-PPCRE](https://edicl.github.io/cl-ppcre/), which is available via Quicklisp for any recent Common Lisp implementation, or you'll need to change the code to use CL-PPCRE directly.